# Raspbian 04-18 Cronjob won't run with @reboot

Tags: raspbian, cron

I'm trying to find any solution to this problem but for some reason I can't manage to make this work properly. The only thing I need is to run a .sh file located in the /home/pi folder.

I did it like this:
1. open terminal
2. sudo crontab -e
3. selected 2 (for /etc/nano)
4. I added at the end of the line: "@reboot /home/pi/Autorun.sh"
5. I created a file (/home/pi/Autorun.sh) and entered the following code:

> ```
> #Mounts shared folder
> sudo mount //<IP-Address>/<folderpath> /home/pi/shared -o username=<Username>,password=<Password>
> ```

6. I added the execution rights with:

> ```
> sudo chmod +x /home/pi/Autorun.sh
> ```

7. reboot
8. I check if the folder is mounted. Result = It's not.
9. Running the script manually to check if it was the script which was not working. Result = Script works perfectly fine.
10. Getting really disappointed and doing more research to find out where the problem is.

So now that I finally reached a very high level of disappointment I don't know what to try else then just throwing it out of the windows. Is anyone able to tell me how to fix the problem?

To give you some more details.
I've downloaded the most recent version of Raspbian today the 04/18 version and installed it on the Raspberry Pi 3. The only things installed are a thightvncserver and xrdp. I've changed the keyboardlayout to german and expanded the filesystem already.

**Solution**

Here is the Solution for my problem.

> @reboot sleep 30 && /home/pi/Autorun.sh

Comment: what happens if you remove the sudo command from the mount command? ... does the log show anything useful?  ........... it is interesting how different languages have different expressions that do not translate very well, in english *very low level of disappointment* means almost no disappointment .... in your case you are experiencing high level of disappointment

Comment: Why not put this mount into `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: stevieb because that folder doesn't even exist :C
@jsotola I just removed the sudo from the script because you are right. It's already used as sudo via crontab. About the logs... ehm... what logs? where can I find them? :C Sorry but I haven't worked that much with linux in ages. Today was like my first real start with it because I want to set something up to move files from my windows computer to the rasppi automaticly and in case of a reboot the folder needs to be added again and I would like to add more scripts and run them with crontab. About the mistake. Yeah I got confused a little bit.

Comment: info about linux logs .... https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-log-files-location-and-how-do-i-view-logs-files/

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root may shed some light

Comment: of course, these days, it's far better to use `systemd` - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd - you then have fine control over when in the boot sequence your script will run

Comment: or even edit `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: What do you mean with _"because that folder doesn't even exist"_. What folder? `//<IP-Address>/<folderpath>` or `/home/pi/shared`? Why do you try to mount a folder that doesn't exist? That will never work.

Comment: Is `//<IP-Address>/<folderpath>` a windows share? Have you tried [fstab](https://wiki.debian.org/fstab)? Cronjob is not ideal for static auto mount!

Comment: @ingo I know I'm stupid but not as stupid enough to try to mount something that doesn't exist to a folder which also doesn't exist. No I meaned the folder /etc/fstab does not exist on the current version of Raspbian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In crontab, you can setup logging by changing your crontab line so it reads:

```
@reboot /home/pi/Autorun.sh > /home/pi/AutorunLog.log 2>&1
```

Then, after crontab will save any output(and errors) to the file `/home/pi/AutorunLog.log`.

Check after boot to see if there are any errors in this file.

Also, you could try running `sudo chmod a+x /home/pi/Autorun.sh` (notice the added `a`)to give *everything* execution permission.

Lastly, try adding a delay(to make sure an internet connection is established) and text output(to make sure your script is running) to your script, like this:

```
sleep 10   #delay 10 seconds
echo "Mounting shared folder..."   #I'm not good at sh files, change this if it's not proper syntax...(it works, though.)
sudo mount //<IP-Address>/<folderpath> /home/pi/shared -o username=<Username>,password=<Password>
echo "mounted file."
```

Comment: thank you already for your help with the logging. It gives me an error message `Network in unreachable` which must refer to the fact that the Network might not be reached at that moment. So I just need to figure out how to run the script after a few seconds. ´sleep 30 && ´ should solve that problem. Will give a definet update later

Comment: thank you very much it helped. I only had to add `sleep 30 &&` to the cronjob and it just immediatly worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your crontab file:

`@reboot sudo mount //<reachable IP addr for SMB share>/<folder> ~/mntPassport<or, a LOCAL folder on your RPi> -o username=guest,password=,vers=1.0`

I've found that the `mount` command has gotten all buggered up in `stretch`; I think because of some fuzziness at RPi.org

If all your shell file does is mount the drive, this will do it. If there are other tasks in your shell script, run it after you've mounted the drive as follows:

`@reboot /bin/bash ~/Autorun.sh > ~/cronjoblog 2>&1`

If it doesn't execute successfully, you'll get the stderr output in the file `cronjoblog`